# RHEL not accepting any passwords

Tags: rhel5, shadow

I have RHEL 5 on virtual machine installed.

I was creating the new user by making entry in /etc/passwd.

I deleted the /etc/shadow file and used pwconv command to make new shadow file.

Now when i restarted the system , it is not  accepting any password

whats should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you attempt to repair the damage in single user mode with a process similar to http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-q-and-a-root-passwd.html

Answer (score 7):

You deleted all of your users' passwords, because they aren't stored in /etc/passwd anymore like they were in the olden days. `pwconv` is *only* for converting entries from passwd to shadow and vice versa -- you should *never* have to use it in day-to-day tasks. Boot into single-user mode as DaveN suggested, restore the file from backup, chalk this one up to experience, and learn the right way to manage user accounts on modern Linux systems. The `useradd` and `passwd` commands exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Which means your system can't find the password in shadow file while authenticating, first you need to create the password for root user after restarting. follow this videos... this helpful for you...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlI4HiRk5-M